# Execute function dynamically passed to the form

Tags: php

I want to apply a user defined function on records retrieved from database.The function to be executed is passed dynamically to the form .How can this be achieved.

```
Eg ;
$function = 'convert_number_to_words';

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    echo '<td>'.$row->num.'</td>';
```

The function convert_number_to_words has to excuted with $row->num as the parameter.How can this be achieved in the above echo statement.

Comment: bad idea, form data is not safe, user could change function name

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row){
    echo '<td>'. call_user_func($func, $row->num) .'</td>'; 
}
```

Or (if you need to pass anonymous arguments) :

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row){
    echo '<td>'. call_user_func_array($func, array($row->num)) .'</td>'; 
}
```

Another solution would be to use reflection:

```
$func = new ReflectionFunction('yourfunc');
$func->invokeArgs( array($row->num));
```

But you should **really** make sure that nobody can execute arbitrary functions on your server

Comment: I think he's asking to not literally use that function name, but rather a dynamic one..

Comment: `call_user_func_array()` is useful in combination with functions that can have a variable number of arguments or something like `func_get_args()`. Since in this case you _know_ all the arguments `call_user_func()` should be sufficient.

Comment: Yep, you are right. But in most cases `call_user_func_array()` suites better. And we don't know if the question is just an example. And as other answers have already introduced `call_user_func()` I decided to use `call_user_func_array()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/call_user_func)

Usage:

```
$function_name = "convert_number_to_words";
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    echo '<td>' . call_user_func($function_name, $row->num) . '</td>';
}
```

Keep in mind that the function must be defined or you will get an error.

Also, don't trust user input, make sure you check what function is specified. You can do this with a white-list for instance.

Comment: But there are also times when $function_name would be empty.i.e there is no function to be executed.I guess I can check for the variable to be not empty.But is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Sure, that's one way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

it also works:

```
$function = 'convert_number_to_words';

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    echo '<td>'.$function($row->num).'</td>';
```